# select whitout empty rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have a fun issue in postgresql.

```
select sum(value1) as v1,
   sum(value2) as v2,
   sum(value3) as v3,
   sum(value4) as v4,
   sum(value5) as v5,
   ...
from (select * from test limit 0)x;
```

result:

```
  v1 |  v2 |  v3 |  v4 |  v5 |  ...
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--...
     |     |     |     |     |  ...
(1 row)
```

Expected: (0 row).

Truth:    (1 row).

I don't want to get empty rows.
How can I get correct results for this case.
Thanks.

Comment: The query will **always** return an empty row because `limit 0` means "no rows at all". So if you don't want that, then why are you using `limit 0` at all? The query makes no sense

Comment: I mean results for my query have some empty rows by using **sum**. Above query is a case to reproduct this issue, and we sure nothing to sum here.

Comment: the expected for above query is 0 rows, not 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `having` clause to filter out null values:

```
select sum(id) 
from ( 
   select * 
   from test limit 0
) x
having sum(id) is not null;
```

Comment: Thank for your help.
I'm using this clause, but I hope have some ways are better, because I have 20+ sum clause on select, and I have to 20+ for having.

Comment: @ThịnhNguyễnThái: you should have included that important bit of information in your question. Broadening the question after you have received an answer is not nice

Comment: Yes, I noted.
Thank you very much!